# How to install the make command in nixos

Tags: nix

I search in the the list of [nix package](https://search.nixos.org/packages). I write make.

I only find `ekam` and it doesn't work.

```
 nix-shell -p ekam
```

Comment: Did you try https://search.nixos.org/packages?

Comment: @RobertHensing Yes . I've writing make. The only result was ekam

Answer (score 2):

Search for gnumake

On nixos:

```
   nix-env -iA nixos.gnumake
```

On a shell:

```
 nix-shell -p gnumake
```

works, but

```
 nix-shell -p
```

is enough

You can now test on a project

```
make
```

Comment: `nix-shell -p` is sufficient, because that calls `mkDerivation`, which includes `stdenv`, which includes `gnumake`.

Comment: @robertHensing Thanks I have tested. It solves this problem (and another that I have not mentioned). How do you know which package are installed if you use nix-shell -p without giving a package name?

Comment: https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-tools-of-stdenv

Comment: @RobertHensing Thanks to your link I know that gnu make, tar .... are include in stdenv.
But I still understand why nix-shell -p is like calling nix-shell -p stendenv